# Why I get error when try append element to document?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have custom method:

```
prependCities() {
  if(process.client) {
    var locations = document.createElement("datalist");
    locations.id = "locations";
    var cities = this.cities;
    for(var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        var opt = cities[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        locations.appendChild(el);
    }​
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]; 
    body.insertBefore(locations, body.children[0]);
  }
}
```

When I run this method on `mounted` hook then get error message:

> SyntaxError: C:\xampp\htdocs\newbabolo\components\MyForm.vue:
>   Unexpected character '​' (420:9)

```
  418 |             el.value = opt;
  419 |             locations.appendChild(el);
> 420 |         }​
      |          ^
  421 |         var body = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]; 
  422 |         body.insertBefore(locations, body.children[0]);
  423 |       }
```

Where I have any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an invisible character at this column.

See here : https://jsfiddle.net/1tm5zqda/

```
prependCities() {
  if(process.client) {
    var locations = document.createElement("datalist");
    locations.id = "locations";
    var cities = this.cities;
    for(var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        var opt = cities[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        locations.appendChild(el);
    }
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]; 
    body.insertBefore(locations, body.children[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/nujrts0m/3/

This works for me. Take a look :)

```
prependCities() {
  if(process.client) {
    var locations = document.createElement("datalist");
    locations.id = "locations";
    var cities = this.cities;
    for(var i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
        var opt = cities[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        locations.appendChild(el);
    }
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]; 
    body.insertBefore(locations, body.children[0]);
  }
}
```